# .Net WebSocket Prototype...Trouble Opening Connection in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0, websocket

Hi I have a Web Application and a Console Application in my C# .Net solution.  I am trying to call a ReverseService class in my Console Application from my Web Application.  In the Console Application in the static void Main function I am running the following code:

```
var host = new WebSocketsHost<ReverseService>(new Uri("ws://localhost:4502/reverse"));
host.AddWebSocketsEndpoint();
host.Open();
Console.ReadLine();
```

I am trying to call this WebSocketEndpoint from my Web Application with the following Javascript code in Chrome 12.

```
if (window.WebSocket) {
            //establishes websocket connection
            websocket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:4502/reverse');

            websocket.onopen = function () {
                $('body').append('Connected.');

                $('#inputbox').keyup(function () {
                    websocket.send($('#inputbox').val());
                });
            };

            websocket.onclose = function () {
                $('body').append('Closed.');
            }

            websocket.onmessage = function (event) {
                $('#outputbox').val(event.data);
            };
        }
```

The websocket.onclose function does in fact get called, but the websocket.onopen function never does.  I've googled and looked on here but to no avail, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Implement `websocket.onerror` - it might help you see what's the problem

Comment: I added     websocket.onerror = function (evt) {
     $('body').append(evt.data);
    };      but it never got hit when I set a breakpoint on it in Chrome 12 and the onclose breakpoint did get hit

Answer (score 0):

The error is almost certainly a mismatch between the protocol versions for your client and server. It looks like you are using the [HTML5 labs prototype](http://html5labs.interoperabilitybridges.com/prototypes/websockets/websockets/info) - if you are using the most recent version then your server is talking WebSockets hybi-09. Chrome implements a much older version of the protocol (I think its [hixie-76](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol-76) but I am not certain).

Your options are:

- Use a WebSocket server that implements hixie-76
- Use a different client implementation. For example, you could use the implementation that is provided with the HTML5 labs prototype. Its a Silverlight plugin with a JavaScript wrapper. You need to include a few scripts and use `new WebSocketDraft` instead of `new WebSocket`. You will also need to drop the clientaccesspolicy.xml file in your wwwroot - see the prototype readme file for more info. Have a look at some of the samples for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir.  I have added the Silverlight.js and jquery.slws.js javascript files along with the Microsoft.ServiceModel.WebSockets.xap file.  Before I was getting nothing in my IE9 browser, but now I am getting the same functionality there as I am in Chrome.  The websocket.onclose event gets called but not the onopen.  I've tried forcing it to use new WebSocketDraft, because my Chrome is recognizing window.WebSocket but still get the same functionality. Also, I do not have a clientaccesspolicy.xml file in my wwwroot, just in the samples I downloaded and the prototype.

Comment: Also, would it matter if I was doing everything locally?  In any event thank you for your reply, I'll keep plugging away at it and see if I can break through some how

Comment: You said "I do not have a clientaccesspolicy.xml file in my wwwroot". Was that a misstype, and you DO have it? Have you made sure that you can access it by going to `http://localhost/clientaccesspolicy.xml` ?

Comment: I did not have it, but I added it and can access it at http://localhost:50679/clientaccesspolicy.xml now.  But whether it's in there or not only the onclose event is being called

Comment: I added it to the root of my client project

Comment: It needs to be accessible on port 80. As I mentioned, you need to be able to access it with `http://localhost/clientaccesspolicy.xml`.

Comment: I copied the clientaccesspolicy.xml to C:\inetpub\wwwroot.  I navigated to http://localhost/clientaccesspolicy.xml and got a 404 not found error, so I created a localhost website in IIS and pointed it to wwwroot, and added an entry for it to my host file. I can now navigate to it, though I feel like that probably isn't the right way to do it.  I ran another test and am still only getting the onclose javascript method called.  My local web project is hitting http://localhost:50679 would that make a difference?

Comment: I have since created a site in my local IIS and attached my client to it.

Comment: Have you tried doing this in a single machine configuration? Just trying to figure out what types of problems we can rule out.

Comment: I'm running locally on a windows 7 machine. Im running IIS 7.5 locally and am using host header bindings on port 80

Comment: Also, I have downloaded your PerfmonDemoPCC from your blog from the Portland Code Camp and am getting the same functionality where only the onclose javascript event gets called

Comment: Interesting. Try following exactly these steps: 
1. unzip the perfmondemopcc solution (download from github).
2. open in VS, and fix the missing references by pointing it at the binaries installed in your Microsoft SDKs\WCF Websockets.
3. replace the .xap and all the .js with the versions that can be found in the prototype folder (there are samples, grab them from the samples).
4. Build, navigate to demo.htm in IE.
I just followed these exact steps (I already had -09 prototype installed and my clientaccesspolicy.xml file in the right spot) and it worked for me.

Comment: I followed these exact steps I brought the xap and js files over from the "game" folder of the prototype, everyone but the smoothie.js file.  I added an onclose event to the websocket in javascript and still it's the only one that gets called

Comment: I assume you've tried the samples that come with the prototype and that they have the same behavior on your machine?

Comment: Yeah I tried the jigsaw example and got the same behavior.  I've run the samples on the html5labs site so I know my browser can run websockets.  Could it be something with the WebSocket object?  The host.Open() does execute, but could it execute without opening a connection? Or could there be some type of security I need to send with it?

Comment: I've noticed in my demo, which I created from your Mix 11 video from Vegas(string reverse), I get the same functionality whether the Console Application is open or closed, which makes me wonder if the websocket is even ever being created.

Comment: I'm really clutching at straws now... you have Silverlight installed, right? Have you used the f12 tools to check your error console for JavaScript errors?

Comment: I do have Silverlight installed I went to:http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/iis-smooth-streaming/demo/ to verify.  I have used the f12 tools I have been setting break points and stepping through the javascript throughout this process.  Is there a way to verify that the Server project has in fact sucessfully opened the websocket?

Comment: Oh and to answer your question my console window is clean

Comment: This would be easier to diagnose if we had a build of Firefox that supported 09 - without it, it is hard to determine where the problem is. Have you tried turning on "break on all exceptions" mode? Perhaps there is an exception that is being swallowed somewhere.

Comment: Sorry for the delay I figured you gave up on me, I tried running in "break on all exceptions" mode, but got nothing from it. Do you know the particular Firefox build that does support 09?

Comment: Pick "Aurora" from http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/channel/ . You may have to modify your JavaScript again because you'll want to use WebSocket not WebSocketDraft.

Comment: I installed Aurora, and ran the app...here is some of the messaging that I got:  [08:41:27.290] GET http://websocket/ClientBin/Microsoft.ServiceModel.Websockets.xap [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 2ms]
[08:41:27.348] GET http://localhost:4502/MessageHandler [HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented 148ms]
[08:41:27.499] Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:4502/MessageHandler. @ http://websocket/WebSocketDemo.htm:15

Answer (score 0):

Use a TCP packet sniffer to watch the protocol handshake.

Successful tests with two protocols :

1. hybi-00/hixie-76 : Firefox 5.0, Safari 5.1.1 use this old protocol with Sec-WebSocket-Key1/Key2...
   There are several free server source codes in C#.
   For example search WebSocket76English.zip. It works even with Safari on iPhone.
2. hybi-06 : Firefox 7.0, Chrome 14 are using the last protocol with Sec-WebSocket-Key.
   The last .Net WebSocket prototype use that protocol.

If someone has a version of WebSocket prototype supporting the old protocol hybi-00, please let me know.

The last specification draft suggest that a server can support several protocols and tell about
the supported versions in field Sec-WebSocket-Version.